# create binary search tree in racket?

Tags: scheme, racket

try to create immutable binary search tree. i started by create constructor to create empty list, and method to add element to tree one by one using the following code.

```
#lang racket
(define (constructTree) '())

(define (addToTree Tree k v)

 (cond [(null? Tree)
           (cons Tree cons((cons k  '()) v))]
       [else
        (cond [(>(car Tree) k)
               (cons Tree cons((cons k  '()) v))
               ]
              [else
               (cons Tree '() cons((cons k  '()) v) )
               ]
              )]
      )
)


(define bst (addToTree (addToTree (addToTree (addToTree (constructTree)3 "3") 1 "1") 2 "2") 5 "5"))
bst
```

what i mean by immutable is 
if i call `(define b0 (constructTree))` 
`b0` should return  `'()`
`(define b1 (addToTree b0 4 "4"))` 
`b1` should return  `'(4 "4" () ())`
`(define b2 (addToTree b1 6 "6"))`
`b2` should return  `'(4 "4" () (6 "6" () ()))`
 ...etc. 
but i am getting this error:**application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: '(3)
  arguments...:** 
any clue why i am getting this error or what i am doing wrong? thank you in advance.

Comment: The immediate issue is that you've put the `cons` outside the parens in some cases.

Comment: @BrendanCannell i didnt understand exactly what you mean , as you  know its my first time code in racket and function language in general

Comment: In all three cases, `(cons Tree cons((cons k  '()) v))` should be `(cons Tree (cons (cons k '()) v))`.

Comment: @BrendanCannell oops i see what you mean, i fixed it but still have the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be looking for something like this:

```
(define emptyTree '())

(define (addToTree Tree k v)
  (match Tree
    ['()
     (list k v '() '())]
    [(list key val left right)
     (if (> k key)
       (list key val left (addToTree right k v))
       (list key val (addToTree left k v) right))]))
```

Note that because of immutability, there's no need to construct a new empty tree each time. You can just make `emptyTree` an alias for the empty list.

Comment: hey Brendan, sorry if i am annoying you, but do you know if is there any buildin function to iterate through the tree and return key and value if exist

Comment: @kero It's no problem. There's no built-in function for that, but it's easy to make it yourself:
`(define (lookup key tree)
  (match tree
    ['() #f]
    [(list k v left right)
     (cond [(> k key) (lookup key left)]
           [(< k key) (lookup key right)]
           [else      (cons k v)])]))` Note that this will return `(key . value)` if the key is present and `#f` otherwise.